# How to disable coreLocation in the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, core-location

How do you disable coreLocation on the iPhone simulator? I'd like to test some stuff but can't find a way to disable it.

Comment: what do you mean disable? the coordinates are hardcoded to the coordinates of Infinite Loop 1.

Comment: I wanted to test how my app behaves when you do not allow it to get the gps-coordinates.

Comment: I have also above process apply in my Iphone application.I thinking to lock or something taking catalyst for stop the working of CLLocationManager Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on the device. When the "Would you allowed this app to use your current location" message pops up, then press No. Then you should be able to test it. This message doesn't come up in the simulator

Comment: willi, U mean the message box is initiating on app start?
If we give grant or something Boolean value for invoke to stopping CLLocationManager class, it will working?