# How to stop Core location in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I was getting current location of user in an iPhone application but now no need to get user's location so i deleted CLLocation framework and deleted the whole relevant things about core location. but still when I ope application, a popup appears and ask " would like to get your current location". I don't want to show this msg so can i prevent my app by this msg?

Any help?
Thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1437495/932011

Comment: according this answer user will have to tap on "Don't allow" once and after that it will not ask but I don't want this msg even for 1 time. When I am not getting location then why this msg popup

Comment: maybe you have a web view (e.g. google maps) in your app, which asks for the location

Comment: Have you used Mapview in your application?

Comment: No i am not using MapView but i am using webview for facebook like button

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning the project? `Product > Clean`

Also, delete the app from your device before building and running it again. That will destroy any saved prefs, etc. that may be left on the device.